# Best algorithm for string parse to array

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, parsing

I have String List like this.

```
"Section 1/Part 1"
"Section 2/Part 1"
"Section 2/Part 2"
"Section 3/Part 1"
"Section 3/Part 2"
"Section 3/Part 3"
```

I want parse it array list in array list like this:

```
Section 1 -> Part 1
Section 2 -> Part 1
          -> Part 2
Section 3 -> Part 1
          -> Part 2
          -> Part 3
```

A simple code example please for understand algorithm

Comment: Split with `/` then categorized based on first item. What's your programming language?

Comment: I already split it. I want create array with it

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution in java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class a {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
      input.add("Section 1/Part 1");
      input.add("Section 1/Part 2");
      input.add("Section 2/Part 1");
      // ...

      HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

      for (String s : input) {
        String[] parts = s.split("/");
        String key = parts[0];
        String value = parts[1];

        ArrayList<String> list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
          list = new ArrayList<String>();
          map.put(key, list);
        }

        list.add(value);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a approach with python, which stores them in a dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for sec, part in [i.split('/') for i in arr]:
...     d[sec].append(part)
... 
>>> 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Section 1': ['Part 1'],
                            'Section 2': ['Part 1', 'Part 2'],
                            'Section 3': ['Part 1', 'Part 2', 'Part 3']})
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you write this in Java ?